# API Error code: 100 facebook OpenGraph

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I have just started making a new Facebook app hosted on heroku and I haven't made any changes yet, but tested the functionality a little bit, to get used to how stuff works. All good until I try the "send message button", to which a dialog appears with the following error log:

```
An error occurred. Please try later

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: 'link' is invalid.
```

I've looked a bit in the related piece of code, and I find nothing wrong, but I am quite new so maybe any of you can help me a little bit to find out what's wrong:

```
    $('#sendToFriends').click(function() {
          FB.ui(
            {
              method : 'send',
              link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
            },
            function (response) {
              // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
              if (response != null) {
                logResponse(response);
              }
            }
          );
        });
```

The reason I don't think there is a problem with `$(this).attr('data-url');` is that the following works (the post to wall button):

```
 $('#postToWall').click(function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
          method : 'feed',
          link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
      );
    });

  }
```

The `getUrl()` function that gets the value is:

```
 public static function getUrl($path = '/') {
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1)
  || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'
) {
  $protocol = 'https://';
}
else {
  $protocol = 'http://';
}

return $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
```

}

Can anyone please help me? I've searched a bit on facebook developers forum and on stackoverflow, but the although the error code was the same, the error message was different. I think this problem is from facebook since method `feed` works, while method `send` does not. Both methods are defined in the facebook sdk

Note:I am using the latest php sdk

Comment: What is the value of `$(this).attr('data-url')`?

Comment: @BradM I'm trying to find out this, but there is a reason I don't think this is the problem. I'll edit the post, it's quite a long answer. Done, edited

Comment: Ok. What is the `data-url` of `$('#sendToFriends')`?

Comment: Same as the other, it's returned by a function `getUrl();` But anyway, has the same value

Comment: Your error message is invalid parameter `link`. Your `data-url` is invalid. It could be a broken string, an empty string, or just numbers. Can you show `getUrl()` ?

Comment: @BradM Done. Anyway, the function is built-in, comes along when I create a new project, and, again, i'm pretty sure it's the same value

Comment: Do `console.error($(this).attr('data-url'));` right before `FB.ui()`.

Comment: The response was 
`Object
error_code: 100
error_msg: "'link'+is+invalid."
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Well there is your problem then. What does the `sendToFriends` element look like in the DOM?

Comment: How can I find out? It's just a class in facebook sdk so I am not sure how to get to it. I just instantiate the `sendToFriends`. I'm quite a newbie so I'm quite disoriented

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/545273815494749?browse=search_513a60f7725054c11915554

Comment: @phwd yeah, that's exactly the same.

Comment: @MihaiB Did you find your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue using the send dialog only.  The feed publishing worked fine which was odd. I was using dynamic querystring parameters on a common URL.

I fixed the issue by forcing Facebook to scrape the URL **before** I attempt to send it via the FB UI Send Dialog.  Use the FB API to hit `graph.facebook.com` with the URL posted in the `id` parameter and a `scrape` parameter set to `true`.

Like so:

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/', 'post', {
    id: '[URL]',
    scrape: true
}, function(response) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        name: '[name]',
        picture: '[Picture URL]',
        link: '[URL]',
        description: '[description]'
    });
});
```

I also answered with this solution to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118858/facebook-api-error-100-link-is-invalid/18232393#18232393).