# Facebook Send dialog with API Error code: 100 ('link' is invalid)

Tags: facebook

I want to provide users with the ability to send money to their Facebook friends through our app (Exvo) by the means of sending an URL to the invitation page via Facebook.

I'm using the 'Send' Facebook dialog (with a redirect to the Facebook webiste). The exact url I'm redirecting the user to is (`to` field has been redacted):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=637466739616439&description=You+can+create+an+Exvo+Account+to+accept+this+money+transfer.&display=page&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.exvo.com%2Finvitations%2F9fb77bda665f0ae8f58843daec80a29b&name=Pawe%C5%82+Go%C5%9Bcicki+would+like+to+send+you+0.01+EUR&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fthemes.exvo.com%2Fstylesheets%2Fimages%2Fcustom_images%2Flogo.png&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.exvo.com&to=username

This present me with a Facebook 'Send' dialog. When I type a custom message and press 'Send', I'm presented with this error:

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: 'link' is invalid.
```

The link param (extracted from the above URL and decoded) is this:

```
https://www.exvo.com/invitations/9fb77bda665f0ae8f58843daec80a29b
```

which is a valid URL, returning a proper 200 response. Using the Facebook debugger I can see that the provided URL does not generate any errors:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.exvo.com%2Finvitations%2F9fb77bda665f0ae8f58843daec80a29b

Only warnings about inferred properties (I have added those at one point as well, but it did not help).

Also note, that once in a while (like 1 in 10), when I click 'Send', the message gets through and I don't see any errors, which makes it even weirder.

Why is this error happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I thought perhaps the issue was that my links were going back to the same canvas URL they were being posted from, but changing that didn't seem to make a difference.  Things worked for a bit earlier today, but the last hour have been broken (I can't even make a link to yahoo.com, for example).  I suspect this may just be 'some code is broken and no one knows or cares about it all that much'.  :/

Comment: I think I got it solved on my end - I had a URL like yours:  
  
foo.com/path/to/code/id/6/rand/ab2e9c8dfb27385  
  
I'd added the rand part to act as a cache buster, and apparently it didn't like those really long ID strings.  Getting rid of those seemed to help, as things are working.  
  
Other things I checked - the og. meta tags per the facebook debugger - the URL one, I made sure there was no redirecting going on.  And I added the missing fields (image, description, etc).  Those were only 'warnings', but completing all of it and losing the long string gave me a working 'send'. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following fixed it for me:

- shorter `token` (this string in the `link` param: `9fb77bda665f0ae8f58843daec80a29b`, which was 32 characters long, now is at 16) as advised by [gkimsal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015464/facebook-send-dialog-with-api-error-code-100-link-is-invalid#comment26458057_18015464)
- accepting [October 2013 breaking changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#q4_2013), which required me to introduce OpenGraph tags to the page and drop `name`, `description` and `picture_uri` params that I was including when constructing the Send dialog redirect uri

Now Facebook, before displaying the Send dialog to the user, must fetch my page beforehand to retrieve the data (from OG: `title`, `description` and `image`) required to display a proper dialog to the user. I think this is what helped the most in my case.

Comment: But the meta tags are not working for me. Still reflecting the same issue. Please advice me..

Answer (score 8):

This might not have been the problem in your case, but just for discoverability: make sure that the URL you are sharing is publicly available on the internet (i.e. not within your firewall or on a local computer).  FB needs to visit your URL to verify its authenticity.

Comment: this hinted me at the right answer. I had to change https to http in my link because I havent actually setup https on my site yet so facebook was likely unable to verify it.

Answer (score 3):

Like mpcabd has pointed out above, make sure to remove anything with fb, fbdev, facebook in the url because when I did, it solved the issue for me. It is probably a bug or a security measure by Facebook. You are always required to pass a redirect_uri with the link and try mentioning a title as well.

Also your link and redirect_uri must be within your domain that you have provided for the app. Ex: if your app domain in app settings is http://stackexchange.com, you cannot share a link like say https://stackoverflow.com/apps/php/fbsdk/etc/login.php, instead you have to share the link https://stackexchange.com/apps/php/etc/login.php which has worked for me

`echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&name=Thanks&link=".$linkToShare."&redirect_uri=".$linkToRedirectTo."'/>Send</a>";`

You can also assign `$title` to something.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out something weird, the same thing happened today on the site I manage, the problem seemed to be that the link contains the word facebook in it, so try to remove **[facebook, fb, or f if it was a whole word]** from your url, it should work, I had a url like `open/ID/facebook/` and the only way it worked when I changed it to `fopen/ID/` which looks stupid!

So may be in your case this is the problem:
`https://www.exvo.com/invitations/9`**`fb`**`77bda665f0ae8f58843daec80a29b`

Try to change your url to something without fb or facebook or anything similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that's not it. I've changed it to something completely different (but leaving the domain name in there) and it still resulted in the dreaded 100 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using the send dialog only. I was using dynamic querystring parameters on a common URL.  The common URL has been scraped by Facebook but each iteration of the common URL **and** the querystring parameters would result in this error if Facebook had not scraped that exact URL previously.

I fixed the issue by forcing Facebook to scrape the URL **before** I attempt to send it via the FB UI Send Dialog.  Use the FB API to hit `graph.facebook.com` with the URL posted in the `id` parameter and a `scrape` parameter set to `true`.

Like so:

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/', 'post', {
    id: '[URL]',
    scrape: true
}, function(response) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        name: '[name]',
        picture: '[Picture URL]',
        link: '[URL]',
        description: '[description]'
    });
});
```

I also answered with this solution to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302835/api-error-code-100-facebook-opengraph/18232504#18232504).