# Facebook API Error 100 'link' is invalid

Tags: facebook

I have my site qa.carryon.com (this is our test site). I have configured it for facebook login and send invitations. In facebook I have configured SiteURL as 'http://login.qa.carryon.com/gs/'. 'login.qa.carryon.com' is our CNAME and we are using Gigya as social third party.

Login is working fine and when users see the list of facebook friends, user will click on one of them and the facebook send dialog triggers. The link parameter for send dialog is something like this 'http://qa.carryon.com/loyalty/signup?userid=xghdt6ys&username=xyz'.

For this link am i getting the error code 100 link invalid or there is other issue in configuration. I am doing this for first time and i cant understand whats going on. Please help i am stuck with no clue.

Comment: Hey Keyur, were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well and I was using dynamic querystring parameters on a common URL.  It seems you are doing the same.

I fixed the issue by forcing Facebook to scrape the URL **before** I attempt to send it via the FB UI Send Dialog.  Use the FB API to hit `graph.facebook.com` with the URL posted in the `id` parameter and a `scrape` parameter set to `true`.

Like so:

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/', 'post', {
    id: '[URL]',
    scrape: true
}, function(response) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        name: '[name]',
        picture: '[Picture URL]',
        link: '[URL]',
        description: '[description]'
    });
});
```

Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982183/facebook-fb-ui-send-dialog-intermittently-returns-invalid-link-error/18217741#18217741).

Does that help?

Comment: I'm currently experiencing similar issues. Already have implemented your solution, but I discovered that apparently sending URLs via this method only supports one query string param. Trying `(...)?A=foo&B=bar` results in `(...)?A=foo%3FB%3Dbar`.